# Multiple annotations found at this line:

Tags: android, xml, string

Faceing this erros

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- error: Multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format; did you mean to add the formatted="false" 
 attribute?
- error: Unexpected end tag string
```

this is my code

```
<resources>
   <string name="app_name">SpeedTest</string>
   <string name="network_edge">Network : EDGE</string>
   <string name="network_3g">Network : 3G</string>
   <string name="network_detecting">Network : Detecting </string>

   <string name="update_speed">%s kbit/sec</string>
   <string name="update_downloaded">Downloaded %s of %s</string>
   <string name="update_connectionspeed">Connection time %s ms</string>

   <string name="update_downloaded_complete">Downloaded %s @ %s kbit/sec</string>

</resources>
```

Facing error from this line

```
<string name="update_downloaded">Downloaded %s of %s</string>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add this :

```
 <string name="update_downloaded" formatted="false">Downloaded %s of %s</string>
```

as you got special characters in this string.

Answer (score 18):

This should be correct if you want to substitute two strings:

```
<string name="update_downloaded">Downloaded %1$s of %2$s</string>
```

Look here: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-format-strings/